# Как получить ссылку на аудио ВК

Tags: python, вконтакте, url, аудио

Занимался парсингом музыки вк на python. В результате получил аудиозаписи, **НО** получил их в таком формате(это **ПРИМЕРЫ!!!**):

> audio45984371_456239025, audio45984371_456239024

и т.п. Вопрос вот в чём: как получить **ссылку** на аудиозапись, по которой ее можно будет скачать(если точнее, то как автоматизировать процесс для любой аудозаписи)?

Есть один "некрасивый" вариант - послать сообщение самому себе, затем принять его, и в параметре `attachments` будет ссылка. Как это сделать по-другому?

Ссылка должна получиться наподобие такой:

> https://cs1-49v4.vkuseraudio.net/p7/63c188880efb43.mp3?extra=91fZRKv6nMs95XYyUSHRHSe1Fo4g49qL2T_pZFAyHXJZ9aVQDpZPPbSpGqaIzoR7yFofspMrkv7tGR7WDOU03G666g2tt7ifvYsR6kwp5L0BD6a-MNDnrCNdgsBtOaM4w-fMn1XIyWUnFwmorJDYyFV4

Если интересно, вот код парсинга музона:

```
import lxml.html
import requests
import re
from itertools import islice
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bot_vk

login = 'login'
password = 'mypassword'
url = 'http://vk.com/'
vk = bot_vk.auth_vk(login = login,password=password)
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language':'ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
'Connection':'keep-alive',
'DNT':'1'
 }
#авторизовываемя для получения музыки
session = requests.session()
data = session.get(url, headers=headers)
page = lxml.html.fromstring(data.content)

form = page.forms[0]
form.fields['email'] = login
form.fields['pass'] = password

response = session.post(form.action, data=form.form_values())
while True:
    response = session.post("https://vk.com/audios"+str(input()))
    #print(response.text)


    #da = re.findall('data-audio="\[(.+)\]',response.text)
    da = re.findall('data-full-id="(.+?)"',response.text)
    print(da)

    qiy = ""
    for i in da:
        qiy+="audio"+str(i)+"," 
    qiy.split(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне удалось вытащить ссылку вот в таком формате:

Трек:  **[PHARAOH - Не по пути](https://sgi1.beeline-kz.vkuseraudio.net/p13/a094def19932e8.mp3?extra=nLFinFtz4cKRlWhxbzu-1s0PY055QRDgwuHXwYbOMOwN2wlGg17S8eWL4lRcJL7qCo_NqDwUtyaZcAxGpbjbyqTrpPzp49zLgdL6xvlxh6-FyY9WdvFeFpNsflBIZOOplkGEs89NPX8xpEP1Tfvc12wilw)**

```
https://sgi1.beeline-kz.vkuseraudio.net/p13/a094def19932e8.mp3?extra=nLFinFtz4cKRlWhxbzu-1s0PY055QRDgwuHXwYbOMOwN2wlGg17S8eWL4lRcJL7qCo_NqDwUtyaZcAxGpbjbyqTrpPzp49zLgdL6xvlxh6-FyY9WdvFeFpNsflBIZOOplkGEs89NPX8xpEP1Tfvc12wilw
```

Трек:  **[Тима Белорусских - Мокрые кроссы](https://sgi1.beeline-kz.vkuseraudio.net/p13/2e077269f04169.mp3?extra=J3SO2gCCQUPp94iOFSMjQiwOf-lGYAMORErnNjqCucAQ_LgxLXCR8qgD-1Iv1SeaW9gMiOHBWoCB0ba97JeA6S7fyMT5-LHMZHD08cz0U6mRpSGE8WMYTmkM6VKpKbfDj1-Vwkb1ulGgQ0qHtuR2-8wpMw)**

```
https://sgi1.beeline-kz.vkuseraudio.net/p13/2e077269f04169.mp3?extra=J3SO2gCCQUPp94iOFSMjQiwOf-lGYAMORErnNjqCucAQ_LgxLXCR8qgD-1Iv1SeaW9gMiOHBWoCB0ba97JeA6S7fyMT5-LHMZHD08cz0U6mRpSGE8WMYTmkM6VKpKbfDj1-Vwkb1ulGgQ0qHtuR2-8wpMw
```

*Песня скачивается если нажать "сохранить аудио как".*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как это автоматизировать то?

Comment: Я просто хочу вставить в код функцию, которая по attachment получает ссылку

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84623/discussion-between--and-).

Comment: нашел решение - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896087/как-получить-ссылку-на-скачивание-attachment-vk-python

Comment: @Иван видел, поставил +. На хабре тоже читал статью